# Problem in setting up google account - "couldn't open connection to server."

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, google-account

I had just installed custom ROM cynogenmod-9(ICS) in my S Plus device and now I am not able to add Google Account in my android device. It gives the following error message,

> Couldn't finish
>   couldn't open connection to server.

So, what is the problem? why I am getting such kind of error?

Comment: ahh, very messy :(

Comment: Is your Internet connection working in your phone? Did you try restarting your phone?

Comment: yes already tried that couple of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there was a network problem or gmail was blocked in my office which was making the server not respond and giving exception -> `couldn't open connection to server.`. I tried at home with my wifi and it worked finally.