# couldn't sign in/there was a problem communicating with Google servers - Xiaomi Redmi 2 Pro

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, google-account, miui, xiaomi

I have a new Redmi 2 Pro and I am unable to sign in to my google account. 
I have `Android 4.4.4 KTU84P` version and `MIUI 77.00.99`.

I'v already tried to login with other google accounts, I disabled 2-step-verification and DisplayUnlockCaptcha. I Cleared data/cache of play store, account manager, service framework. All tries were unsuccessful.
I can login to my gmail through the browser on my phone.

The error message: **Couldn't sign in/There was a problem communicating with Google servers/ Try again**.

Apps used to sign in: `Google Account Manager 4.4.4-1227136` and `Google Play store version 5.4.12` (these apps are initially installed on the phone)

Steps to sign in on the phone:

1. Add google account -> Existing account -> user+password -> error message
2. Start Google Play Store -> Existing account -> user+password -> error message

**UPDATE**

After a long night search, I found out that the phone came with a vendor specific ROM, namely `77.00.99.00`. The official version looks like `7.1.0.0`. So, I'm thinking to flash the ROM. I have no idea what else is installed beside the official package.

Comment: Much better, thanks! There was no error number given along? (if you just missed that: our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) holds a quite comprehensive list of those with links). All things I'd suggest you've already tried (clearing cache/data, checking network connection). Might still be a server-hickup curing itself within a few hours/days/years (oops). So I've got to leave this to someone else. Meanwhile, make sure to check the messages in the "related" section (to the right using a desktop browser).

Comment: Related: [Cannot sign-in Google account on Samsung Galaxy S with 2-step authentication](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/45771/16575) / [Nexus 10 cannot sign into Google Accounts](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47623/16575) / [There was a problem communicating with Google servers, try again later](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/106494/16575) / [Problem in setting up google account - “couldn't open connection to server.”](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32565/16575)

Comment: No  error number was given and if I hit next at the bottom it appears the same error message.  I'v been trying to login since yesterday...  do you know if my `play store`  version is all right or should I install an older one?

Comment: You can always try to "uninstall updates" (via *Settings › Apps* and its "All" tab). They'll re-install again soon, but this sometimes helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem was with the ROM, Gearbest replaced the official one with a buggy one. I flashed the `latest stable global ROM MIUI 7.1.1.0` with a little trick described by **Bilhouse** in the miui global forum [here](http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=115492&page=11#lastpost.)

The steps are as follows:

1. downloaded the `Latest Stable Global ROM` from [here](http://en.miui.com/a-234.html) for `Redmi 2 version 2014813`
   file: wt88047_global_images_V7.1.1.0.KHJMICK_20151209.0000.6_4.4_global
2. downloaded the `China ROM` for mobile version `2014811`, I used the one mentioned in this post [here](http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=94587&pid=1844478). file name wt86047_images_5.4.3_4.4_cn_94aabfc129
3. from the China ROM I copied `NON-HLOS.bin` file and replaced the one in the Global ROM - if you don't do this than you wont have a functional network module and you wont be able to connect to any network.
4. Flashed the ROM with `fastbool` as described in my first link.
5. At my first try of flashing, I encountered an error massage: **mismatching image and device** in fastboot, which I solved by changing the name of the folder from `wt88047...` to `wt86047...` after this I was able to flash the ROM and tired again but this time the folder name should start as ti was originally wt88047...

Comment: Redmi 2 Pro is also called at some places Redmi 2 2GB RAM/16GB or Redmi 2 Enhanced.

Answer (score -1):

1.- Root your device (of course)

2.- Editing the file

You will need a proper editor

On your device open your browser and go to: www.ghisler.com/android.htm

Download and Install Total Commander for Android... and open it

OR DOWNLOAD BELOW

3.- Browse with Total Commander to root/etc

(hint: on the right side of the screen there's a shortcut to system folder.. look for etc/ and you will find it)

Long tap on "hosts" > edit file > Totalcmd-Editor

Open etc/hosts and edit the file. Just put # before 74.125.93.113 android.clients.google.com.

4.- SAVED

Edited file should look like this:

127.0.0.1 localhost

## 74.125.93.113 android.clients.google.com

remember: based on my own observation it should be look like this:

127.0.0.1(just one space)localhost

## 74.125.93.113(just one space)android.clients.google.com

5.- Turn OFF your device.

6.- Got it on Recovery Mode

7.- Factory reset, wipe data.

8. Reboot your device.
9. Once the phone reboots, input your google account information when the phone asks for it.

10.- Sync to your account and contacts

METHOD 2:

1. Make sure you have a ROOT ACCESS on your Device.
2. Install Root Explorer, Run App, Grant SU Access.
3. Browse root / etc... at the top of your screen you will see mount R/O and mount R/W...

4.Tap mount R/W

5.Look for host file, long press it and open with text editor.

6. just Add # (pound sign) on the first number.

like this:

## 74.125.93.113(just one space)android.clients.google.com

SAVE IT and Reboot.

Comment: So, you also forgot to mention the [source](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22Browse+with+Total+Commander+to+root/etc%22) and give appropriate credit to author(s), right? Follow [How to reference material written by others](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: I'v already seen this advice elsewhere, but I am not professional in Android but I'm using Linux, so I choose not to try yet. Please tell me what actually means this modification. # is commenting that line, if yes, why do I have to do that, is the given IP address wrong? I'm  a programmer, please take into consideration in your answer.

Comment: @Elod there is what we call rooting your phone [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/amazon-fire/general/installing-google-framework-playstore-t3216122/post64546621#post64546621)